# Multi Insert issue in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript, meteor

First, I know about the way in the Leaderboard example, which is using a loop to do the multi insert. However, when I do this, I get a mongoDB error on the server console, stopping the insert. I thought that the issue could be from the fact that coffeescript always returns, so I tried it in pure JS and it still didn't work (Except on the browser console).

Here is the code for the multi insert

```
#find opponent deck
    opponent_deck = (Card_Reference.find deck_id: opponent.deck).fetch()

# save a temporary deck
    _.each opponent_deck, (card) ->
        Deck.insert card
```

Is something wrong with the code itself?

Comment: what's the error you get? Is it something about duplicate index keys?

Comment: the error was about something along the lines of "Object is not a function". It was a long error (around 8 lines). But yeah, after deleting the ID field, it worked perfectly well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tarang is right, you should remove `_id` from the card before you reinsert the card. Also, you probably want to update the `deck_id` parameter to reflect that you're adding the card to the temporary deck:

```
# save a temporary deck
    _.each opponent_deck, (card) ->
        delete card._id
        card.deck_id = tmp_deck_id
        Deck.insert card
```